# KeyManagerFactory cannot recover key, yet it opens in keytool

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

```
String keyStorePath = "2keystore.jks";
String keyStoreType = "JKS";
String keyStorePassword = "mypass";

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
InputStream ksis = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(keyStorePath);
keyStore.load(ksis, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
ksis.close();
// Above seems to work fine

KeyManagerFactory kmf =
      KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
  kmf.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

// Above throws exception:
// UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
```

Yet, using keytool, I can view the contents of `2keystore.jks` like so:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore 2keystore.jks | more
Enter keystore password:  mypass
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

Alias name:
...
```

Any idea what could be the problem when trying to load this keystore into the `KeyManagerFactory`?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your keystore is where you expect it to be on the classpath? Is `ksis` not null for example? Can you list the keystore aliases once you've loaded it?

Comment: The keystore 'ksis' isn't null... it loads.  I think I figured out the problem... the keystore loads with the password for the overall keystore, but the KeyManagerFactory requires a different password for the key-pairs contained within the keystore.

Comment: The KMF password is the password that protect the keys themselves, whereas the password used by KeyStore.load(...) protects the overall keystore. Whether these passwords are different depends on how you've built the keystore.

Comment: Got it-- that's a good clarification, and one I admittedly wasn't aware of until getting past this w/ trial and error.   Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I had to specify a different password for the `KeyStore` as opposed to the `KeyManagerFactory`.

This was a mistake I made in creating the KeyStore file.  I used [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) to convert my PKCS#12 key to a JKS, which reset the password to the key-pairs inside the KeyStore to 'password', and I missed this on the first go-around.

So using Portecle, I was able to reset the password on the key-pairs contained within the overall KeyStore to the value I was expecting and then everything worked fine.

Thanks Bruno

Comment: You don't need to convert your PKCS#12 file to use it as a keystore, just use `PKCS12` as the keystore type (in this case, it's the same password for key and store).

Comment: +1 Good to know.  I imagine one would also need to specify a different property when setting the "javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType" property to be "PKCS12" rather than "JKS" in this case.